# Cancellation law of ideals in a certain ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain, dedekind-domain

Let $R$ be a integral domain satisfying the following property.

> For any non-zero ideal $A$ of $R$,
>   there exist $a \in R\ (a \neq 0)$ and
>   a non-zero ideal $B$ of $R$ 
>   such that $AB=(a)$.

Let $A,B,C$ 
be non-zero ideals of $R$. I can prove that

> $AB=AC \Rightarrow B=C$.

I then want to prove the following:

> $B \subset A \Rightarrow$
>   there exists a non-zero ideal $C$ of $R$
>   such that $B=AC$.

I got a hint as follows: There exists an ideal $J$ and $a \ne 0$ such that $AJ=(a)$. Then since $JB\subset AJ$ we have that 
$C=(1/a)JB$ is an ideal in $R$. Lastly, note we have $AC=B.$
Shubhodip Mondal's answer helps me to understand that the hint is nothing but a proof.

My additional question is to prove

> Every non-zero prime ideal is a maximal ideal.

Actually if $R$ is a Dedekind domain then every non-zero prime ideal is principal hence maximal. For instance see proof of Theorem 3.32 [here](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=_fU8k16vbsMC&pg=PA143&lpg=PA143&dq=A%20Dedekind%20domain%20is%20a%20UFD%20if%20and%20only%20if%20it%20is%20a%20PID&source=bl&ots=RF95GkUeM3&sig=-4E3fLO6jrRpMdWIi9GjWYi5Sgw&hl=vi&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTvZy9o8zMAhVBF5QKHXp6Amw4ChDoAQg3MAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).
But just given a property of $R$ in the beginning, how can we prove that?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: We have $JB \subseteq AJ = (a)$. Thus $(1/a)JB \subseteq R$. You could view this as an equality over the quotientfield $K$ of $R$. The so called fractional ideals are the $R$-submodules of $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AJ = ( \alpha)$.

$B \subseteq A$. So for  $b_i \in B$ and $j_i \in J$ , $ \sum  b_i j_i \in AJ = (\alpha) $.

So, $\frac{1}{\alpha} \sum b_i j_i \in R$.

Therefore, $\frac 1 \alpha  BJ$ happens to be an ideal of $R$ and you do not need anywhere that $\alpha$ is an unit.

Comment: I have a follow-up question: In rings described above, is every non-zero prime ideal is maximal?

Comment: Well, I deleted the previous comment. Anyway,

Let P be a prime ideal and M is a maximal ideal containing P. So there exists J such that MJ = P. Now M and J contains MJ. if both containment is proper, then there is a m in M which is not in MJ = P and a j in J which is not in MJ = P. But mj is in P contradicting the fact that P is a prime ideal.

Otherwise, if MJ = J, then M = (1) a contradiction. So only possibility is MJ = M. Then J = (1) So P = MJ = M. Therefore, P is maximal.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: I really like your solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's very easy to show that every non-zero prime ideal is maximal.

Let $P$ be a non-zero prime ideal which is not maximal and $M\supsetneq P$ a maximal ideal. Then, there is a non-zero ideal $C$ such that $P=CM$. From the definition of prime ideals we get $P\supseteq C$, so $C=P$. Thus $PR=P=PM$ which gives $M=R$, a contradiction.